# Which R functions are correct for calculating partial eta squared in multiple linear regression (with interaction terms)?

Tags: r, linear-regression

There are a few functions in R available for calculating partial Eta Squared, such as: `effectsize::eta_squared`, `rstatix::partial_eta_squared`, `sjstats::anova_stats`, `heplots::etasq`, `DescTools::EtaSq`, `lsr::etaSquared`

However, when running them on a multiple regression model (with an interaction), I get different partial eta squared estimations depending on the function I use.  It seems that **the first three functions produce the same estimates but which differ from the estimates produced by the latter three functions**.

Example: a LM model specification is as follows:

`istanb.lm.INT2   <- lm(istanb.uk.NA   ~ crt.uk + aot.uk.NA +  PolitID + SBS.NA + sex + age + education  + PolitID * aot.uk.NA, data = istanb.df, na.action = na.omit)`

#Partial eta squared estimates from `effectsize::eta_squared`, `rstatix::partial_eta_squared`, `sjstats::anova_stats`:

- crt.uk                **0.008**
- aot.uk.NA             **0.199**
- PolitID               **0.272**
- SBS.NA                **0.020**
- sex                   **0.027**
- age                   **0.002**
- education             **0.006**
- aot.uk.NA:PolitID     **0.025**

#Partial eta squared estimates from `heplots::etasq`, `DescTools::EtaSq`, `lsr::etaSquared`:

Partial eta^2

- crt.uk                **0.013**
- aot.uk.NA             **0.071**
- PolitID               **0.140**
- SBS.NA                **0.029**
- sex                   **0.019**
- age                   **0.002**
- education             **0.006**
- aot.uk.NA:PolitID     **0.025**

The summary of the multiple linear model in question is presented in the following figure:

[model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDcKG.png)

I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on what seems
to be the cause of these differences, and **which calculation is more appropriate for a multiple linear model with an interaction**.

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards,
Marina

Comment: This seems to be less a coding question and more an interpretation and definition problem. As such voting to migrate to CrossValidated.com . It's possible this has been askedc before on that site and you should do some searching there. Searching on "eta-squared interaction" I got over forty hits including: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6824/calculating-and-interpreting-effect-sizes-for-interaction-terms/6826?r=SearchResults&s=8|0.0000#6826

Comment: Thanks, I have posed this question to CrossValidated.com. However, if someone knows and can explain the differences in the coding of these two sets of functions I would appreciate it as well.